# NoSuchMethodError in running test case for rest services using junit and grizzle

Tags: java, rest, junit, jersey-test-framework

I had a test case to test the jersey 2.x rest service.. But got NullPointerException.. Seems to me there is a jar issue between jsr311 and javax.ws.rs-api . I didn't find any jsr311 with any dependencies.. Not sure why the servlet is taking is refering jsr311.jar

Below are my code changes

HelloWorldServiceTest.java

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext.Builder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerException;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mkyong.rest.HelloWorldService;

import rest.RestApplication;

public class HelloWorldServiceTest extends JerseyTest{

    @Path("hello")
    public static class HelloResource {
        @GET
        public String getHello() {
            return "Hello World!";
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class );
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected ServletDeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext.forPackages(HelloWorldService.class.getPackage().getName()).build();
        //return ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(HelloWorldService.class))).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleNode() throws Exception {
        final String hello = target("hello").path("Test").request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println("Response"+ hello);
        assertEquals("Jersey say : Test", hello);
    }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Below is my exception i got

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values.lazy(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:147)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't mix your Jersey versions. You are using 2.6 and 2.13. Without testing, I'd say this is most likely the problem

Comment: Hi @peeskillet, I changed my pom.xml as below with same version jars                                                            `<jersey-version>2.23.1</jersey-version><swagger-version>1.5.9</swagger-version><jersey-test-framework>2.23.1</jersey-test-framework>
`.But still i am facing the issue but different one.. its jsr 311 exception i guess. But when i saw the dependency hierarchy of pom.xml.. I didnt see jsr 311.. `exception:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map; `

Comment: Do you have any Jersey 1 dependencies? Is this error happening when running the test or running on the server?

Comment: When i hit the service over the browser i am able to get the response properly without error.. but when i running the test case with the code i given  i am getting this server error.. I am using Jersey2.. I dont have any Jersey 1, but i am using JBoss server

Comment: Do you have any other dependencies, like javaee?

Comment: I am using JBoss 9 which is using J2EE7, i add dependencies only which i had mentioned in the pom.xml..